# What does "Fix this up" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, mollys-game

With tight security in *Molly's Game* (2017), player Shelly attempted to put a 7 million dollar Monet painting
as payment for the poker game, but Molly, the person running the poker game, rejected
the painting as a form of payment:

> Molly: Security can't stand in front of the door. **Fix this up**,
> come on back, and I'll extend you credit tonight up to one and a half.

What does "Fix this up" mean?

Comment: Did you check any definitions? [Fix up](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fix): "to smooth over, solve". Besides, this is an English comprehension question, for which [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) is more suitable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an English comprehension question.

Comment: @Joachim - A good guess, but wrong. She doesn't mean to fix the situation, she means to rehang the painting. You're not wrong that it's about comprehension though...

Comment: If "*she means to rehang the painting*", doesn't that mean "*fix the situation*" (solve it by reversing and going back to point #0) too?

Comment: @OldPadawan - She literally means "fix that [back] up", but yes, that would also resolve the situation.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because it relates to the meaning of a phrase in the context of a movie. Questions like this can help movie viewers better understand and appreciate the respective movie. If one doesn't understand the meaning of a phrase or word in a movie, then that will hamper their comprehension of the movie. Also, we shouldn't push questions away to other sites if they're on-topic here.

Comment: @galacticninja I believe the context would have made it clear if the OP knew the meaning of the phrase. My initial comment was a valid definition based on the information given by the OP. That Molly was suggesting to rehang the painting was only clear to Valorum because they must have seen/read more of the scene, as "fix [the painting] up" is not colloquial use. This still boils down to pure English language comprehension, and doesn't inherently add anything useful to the appreciation of the scene (only to the OP).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She's referring to the painting being *rehung* in his apartment, literally to affix the painting ('this') back up to the wall on which he found it.

In [the original screenplay](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/mollys-game-2017.pdf) the wording is very subtly different, but shows the intention more clearly.

> MOLLY stares at the painting blank-faced.
>
> **MOLLY:** (pause—calmly) *That is...an authentic Monet?*
>
> **HELLY:** ***Grabbed it right off the wall.***
>
> **MOLLY:** (pause) *You came over here carrying a Monet.*
>
> **HELLY:** *I was driven. And I have security outside the door.*
>
> **MOLLY:** *Okay. Helly, here's what I need you to do. I need you to get this, what, 20--?*
>
> **HELLY:** *27.*
>
> **MOLLY:** *--27-million dollar painting out of here right now. And your, I assume, armed security--?*
>
> **HELLY:** *Sure.*
>
> **MOLLY:** *--can't stand in front of the door. **Fix that up**, come on back and I'll extend you credit tonight up to one and a half.*